# how to show the single button in uilocalnotification

Tags: iphone, ios

Iam developing one application.In that i need to show the local notification with single button.So pease tell me how to show single button in notification.

Comment: In addition to @rckoenes answer, giving the user one option (depending on what it is) may not even be allowed by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 5 the default setting is to use the Notification center, thus there is no more dialog with buttons any more.

Also you should not force a user to do something, thats bad design.